# Why is the dot illegal in a Java identifier?

Tags: java, syntax

We know some of this syntax won't compile, specifically the line where I'm explicitly referring to the class name for a variable.

```
class Main {

    static String Main.s1 ="output"; //won't compile
    static String s2 = "output";

    public static void main(String... s1) {
        System.out.println("output");
    }
}
```

The `Main.s1 ="output";` gives a compiler error. But we do know that the following is ok:

```
class Main {

    static String s2 = "output";

    public static void main(String... s1) {
        System.out.println(Main.s2);
    }
}
```

Similarly, the following is also ok.

```
class Main {

    static String s2 = "output";

    public static void main(String... s1) {
        Main.s2 = "baz";
        System.out.println(Main.s2);
    }
}
```

It's just at declaration that the compilers complains. I read that there are these rules for identifiers in Java

- reserved words cannot be used. they cannot start with a digit but
- digits can be used after the first character (e.g., name1, n2ame are
  valid). they can start with a letter, an underscore (i.e., "_") or a
  dollar sign (i.e., "$").
- you cannot use other symbols or spaces
  (e.g., "%","^","&","#").

So apparently it is not legal to use a dot in an identifier. I agree is it unnecessary, but there is a lot of other unnecessary legal code.

Any reason why the dot is illegal in a Java identifier?

Comment: Don't your second and third examples show why the first is not allowed; it would make it really ambiguous where the variable name starts

Comment: The dot `.` is illegal in variable names for the same reason you may not use `+`, `|`, or `[` in a variable: they are all operators. In particular, the dot is both the namespace traversal operator (looks up a declaration within a package or class) and also the field access operator (look up a field or method in an object instance).

Comment: `Main.s2 = "baz";` In this line the dot is not part of an identifier, but serves to disambiguate which 's2' you are referring to. If you had written `s2 = "baz";`, for example, you may have been referring to a local variable.

Comment: Pretty much the same reason you can't have `+` in an identifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot is used to denote the end of one identifier and the start of a sub-item of that identifier:

```
package1.package2.class.innerclass.method
```

When the compiler reaches each `.`, it knows it's reached the end of one identifier and is moving on to the next. If dots were allowed in names, then the method might actually be called `innerclass.method`. If you then also have a class called `class.innerclass` in `package1.package2` and a class called `innerclass` in `class`, then how is the compiler to resolve what it is that you are referring to?

Comment: "When the compiler reaches each '.', it knows it's reached the end of one identifier." - May not be technically accurate. Consider ellipsis usage: `void f(T... x)`. The first dot may be considered the end of 'T'. but the second and third dots do not signal the end of separate identifiers.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is demonstrated in your second two examples, it would make the code ambiguous for no real value (how often does it really make sense to put a dot in a variable name)

Take this line

`int b = Main.a`

It is quite clear under real java what this means; class `Main` has a field `a` and you'd like to set it's value to b.

Under your system it might mean that **or** there might be a local variable called `Main.a`. They may both exist!

So basically; you can't use the dot because java is already using it (you could make more of an argument for some of the other symbols but it's never a bad idea to reserve some symbols you "might use", especially given java's focus on backwards compatability)